# Yii2 - trasitive dependency in active records

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have 3 tables.

`Product [ProductId, ProductName], 
VendorProduct[VPid, ProductId, VPprice], 
Deals[DealId, VPid, DealPrice]`

I want to show the Deals using active records in GridView. I defined the relations but unable to access the ProductName from table Product.

`Deals.*, VendorProduct.VPid, Product.ProductName`

This is the result I want.
My DealsSearch model is like.

```
$query = Deals::find()->joinWith(['vendorProduct', 'vendorProduct.product']);
```

And I pass that `$query` to `ActiveDataProvider` like this.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $query,
]);
```

My GridView Code :

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'DealId',
        'VPid',
        'DealPrice',
        [
          'label' => 'Product Name',
          'attribute' => 'vendorProducts.product.ProductName',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

It is simple with the normal join query, but I need to do this with `ActiveRecord` class.

Edit:

In short, I want result of the following query with ActiveRecord.

```
SELECT Deals.*, VendorProduct.VPid, Product.ProductName
FROM Deals
JOIN VendorProduct ON VendorProduct.VPid = Deals.VPid
JOIN Product ON Product.ProductId = VendorProduct.ProductId;
```

I got following array when I print the `$model->vendorProduct` in my view.
(I removed extra columns for the sake of readability).

```
backend\models\VendorProducts Object
(
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [VPid] => 3
            [ProductId] => 4175
            [VPprice] => 0
        )
    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [product] => backend\models\Product Object
                (
                    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
                        (
                            [ProductId] => 4175
                            [ProductName] => Human Resource Consultancy
                        )

                )

        )

    [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
    [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
    [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : I edited question for understanding.

Comment: If you want result in active record just use [all()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#all()-detail) after query.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : I printed that result in view, it shows me the data in array, but I am enable to access it. It is showing the data, but not syncing with GridView.

Comment: You want to display data in gridview?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the data in gridview.

Comment: If [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/) won't help you then I have to set a demo for you.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : I already gone through that but I can't figure it out. Can you please set a demo?

Comment: yes, give me some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GridView**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'vendorProduct.VPprice',
        [
          'label' => 'Product Name',
          'attribute' => 'vendorProduct.product.ProductName',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: I tried same logic before posting the question, but it is not working.

Comment: @InsaneSkull: I added the output array in my question (its not possible to add it here in comments).

Comment: @kishor10d. Well then there is no any errors with your code either,  update how you tried with gridview.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : I updated the question with code of GridView.

Comment: @kishor10d. Replace `attribute` with `value`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : actually I done the same before, but in your answer, you mentioned it in attribute, so I tried that. Yet won't work.

Comment: @kishor10d. Well man it's a pain to understand what's wrong virtually, though it's too easy with gridview. Let me think other workaround

Comment: @InsaneSkull : hey, just done with a demo with same scenario (city->state->country) and nicely working with your solution. I need to check with my relationship code again. Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: @kishor10d. no problem. If still don't work, i will make full demo by tomorrow.

Comment: @InsaneSkull : Actually I have another class variable $ProductName which is assigned as null, thats why it is not printing.
So, I use viaTable() and done with the task. It works fine. I will update that as answer to this question itself.

Comment: @InsaneSkull :


```public function getProduct()
{

 return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), ['ProductId' => 'ProductId'])
   ->viaTable(VendorProducts::tableName(), ['VPid' => 'VPid']);

}```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by using custom value as follows..

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'DealId',
        'VPid',
        'DealPrice',
        [
          'label' => 'Product Name',
          'attribute' => 'vendorProducts.product.ProductName', // here use attribute ProductName, 
          'value'=> 'vendorProducts.product.ProductName',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Comment: nope, it will produce error ```trying to access property of non-object```

Comment: refer updated answer, i m not sure about the `attribute` whether it is  `ProductName` or something else